# How can I configure Alpakka Slick to enable streaming from my database in Java?

Tags: java, postgresql, slick, akka-stream, alpakka

I am trying to stream results from a query using Slick within a Java application, using Akka Streams and Postgres:

```
Source mySource = Slick.source(
  slickSession,
  "SELECT * from message where started_instant is null",
  (this::createQueueItemFromSlickRow));
```

In the [Slick documentation](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.2.0/dbio.html) it is clear that in order to stream with Postgres, additional parameters need to be set. However, I can only find Scala examples, and there is no information in the [Alpakka documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/slick.html) on how to configure this.

As it is, I can't process any new objects that come into the database after the stream has started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, the [Slick documentation](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.2/dbio.html#streaming) notes the following:

> Note: Some database systems may require session parameters to be set in a certain way to support streaming without caching all data at once in memory on the client side. For example, PostgreSQL requires both `.withStatementParameters(rsType = ResultSetType.ForwardOnly, rsConcurrency = ResultSetConcurrency.ReadOnly, fetchSize = n)` (with the desired page size `n`) and `.transactionally` for proper streaming.

[Alpakka's Slick support recently exposed the `PreparedStatement` in its Java DSL](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/pull/2318)<sup>1</sup>, which you can use to set the aforementioned parameters if you cannot use the Scala API. For example:

```
PreparedStatement statement =
  connection.prepareStatement(
    "MY SQL STATEMENT",
    ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, // java.sql.ResultSet
    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
```

Check out the [`SlickTest.java`](https://github.com/akka/alpakka/blob/master/slick/src/test/java/docs/javadsl/SlickTest.java) class and the above pull request for more details.

<sup>1</sup>This change is part of the upcoming Alpakka 2.0.2 release. (Version 2.0.1 is the current release at the time of this writing.)